# Gradle runs webpack task but it has no effect

Tags: gradle

I have the following gradle build setup:

```
node {
    version = '8.9.1'
    // If true, it will download node using above parameters.
    // If false, it will try to use globally installed node.
    download = true
    //the work directory for npm
    npmWorkDir = file('src/main/ui')
    //the directory for node_modules
    nodeModulesDir = file('src/main/ui')
}

task webpack(type: YarnTask, dependsOn: 'npmInstall') {
    args = ['build']
    // the same name as the script in package.json
}

task copyTask(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'webpack') {
    from 'src/main/ui/bundle.js'
    into 'src/main/resources/public/static/js/'
}

processResources.dependsOn 'copyTask'
```

And the following scripts in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "npx webpack-dev-server",
  "build": "npx webpack",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

This is `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader'
    }]
  },
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

Gradle runs the build script (I can see `npx webpack` in the gradle log) but I don't see the build.js. I can see it getting generated when I run `npx webpack` myself in terminal. I'm wondering why it doesn't get generated when gradle runs it.

Comment: Do you have a SSCCE?

Comment: No, it involves webpack configuration and gradle scripts. It would be very hard to have a SSCCE for such problem.

Comment: Ok then. Have you tried running the script with `-i` switch? You should see in the output whether the task was run or not and what's the reason for skipping it if so.

Comment: hmmm.... it says: `Task ':webpack' is not up-to-date because: Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.` but the webpack task has an output defined in `webpack.config.js`

Comment: This is not the same output. It seems that the task is run. It would be skipped if it _was_ up-to-date. Have you searched for `build.js` in the entire project folder? Or maybe in one particular place only? It's hard to help without any example.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't run the task. I changed the entry in `webpack.config.js` to a file that doesn't exist, and it didn't fail. I changed it output filename in the same file to `bundlex.js` and no such file got created.

Comment: It rather runs the task which is probably misconfigured. Try running it with `-d` switch to debug.